# How to config Intellij to recognize annotations inside Angular2 constructor

Tags: angular, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij 14.1.7, with configuration for typescript as below.

[Typescript configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtPQp.png)

I have a problem that my Intellij does not recognize any parameters with annotations inside Angular2 typescript constructor.

[Typescript constructor with annotated parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUcw5.png)

Then, it marks the rest of the typescript .ts file with all red errors.
It is so annoying.

Does anyone know how to configure Intellij to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Idea 14, released in 2014, provides no support for TypeScript annotations, neither it supports Angular 2.
Your only option is updating to the most recent Idea version that supports most recent TypeScript and Angular features